# Как изменить цвет блока слайдера bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите, как я могу изменить цвет блока? Он статично белый, не могу никак стилями его подбить, подскажите, в чем может быть дело? style уже во все блоки закидываю, !important тоже не помогает.

```
{% block content %}
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Дашбоард{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly.css"/>
    
</div>

<body style="background-color: #152A3D;">
    <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" style="background-color: #152A3D !important;">
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="background-color: #152A3D;">
            {% for manager, plot_html in plots.items %}
                <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" data-bs-interval="5000" style="background-color: #152A3D !important; ">
                    {{ plot_html | safe }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        
    </div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавил во views где описывается plotly график:

```
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor=None)
fig.update_layout(paper_bgcolor='rgb(41, 79, 116)')  # Цвет фона вокруг графика
```

Проблема решилась.